# Search for occurrences of text in a long line in less

Tags: search, less

I am using `less` to view a file with many long lines. `less` automatically wraps these lines, but when I use `/` and `n` to search for something, it only shows the first occurrence of  the text on a line. However, I want to see all occurences of the search result on the wrapped line.

Comment: I believe the way less reacts to `/` and then `n` is the way it is supposed to. If you want to view multiple occurrences of the same word on the same line, you need to use something like `vi`. If you think you will accidentally edit a file which should not be edited, use `view` instead or `vi -R`. Both are effectively the same thing